# error in gridview databinding expression: 'input string not in correct format'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is the line that is throwing the error:

```
<asp:CheckBox ClientID='<%# Eval("ProviderName") + "@" + Convert.ToString(Container.DataItemIndex) %>' runat="server"
```

Here is my data source:

```
var patientProviders = (from t in adminDb.tbl_patients_patients_to_providers
                                        join p in adminDb.tbl_patients_providers on t.ProviderId equals p.ProviderId_this
                                        join ps in adminDb.tbl_patients_providers_to_specialties on p.ProviderId_this equals ps.ProviderId
                                        join s in adminDb.tbl_patients_providers_specialties on ps.SpecialtyId equals s.ProviderSpecialtiesId_this
                                        where t.PatientId == patientId
                                        orderby t.PatientToProviderId_this
                                        select new { p.ProviderName, s.ProviderSpecialty, t.ProviderTypeId }).ToList();
```

ProviderName is a string.

I just cannot figure out why the input is not formatted correctly...

Comment: @EhsanSajjad why would it be null?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `Convert.ToString` can handle `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Control.ClientId only has a "get" so i think it's readonly:

```
- from MSDN - 
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public virtual string ClientID { get; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all ClientID is a reaonly property. You have only a getter.

But If you have a problem with the expression you want to bind use `GridView.RowUpdating` event handler which allows you to manipulate the expression you want to bind in codebehind.(helping way to debug your problem)